# Search by pattern and operator 'LIKE'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table with a date column (VARCHAR), the date is presented in a table in the date column in two ways:

1.:

```
05.01.2020
```

and 2.:

```
2020-01-05
```

I request to find / return all rows that are displayed in the 1st way: `05.01.2020`

> I try to use the 'LIKE' clause this way:

```
SELECT * FROM     `myTable`
WHERE             `date_column`
LIKE              '%(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2}).(\d{4})%';
```

The SQL server performs this query without error, but with zero rows returned. I will probably have a mistake somewhere.

Comment: LIKE (it is operator, not clause) do NOT perform [regular expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) matching.

Comment: if there is NO another pattern values in this field, check for a dot: `WHERE INSTR(date_column, '.')`.

Comment: Thank you. I have been learning SQL for a short time. I'm grateful. @Akina

Comment: "date column" and "VARCHAR" are contradictory. If the column is VARCHAR, it's **NOT** a date column. Use the correct type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple:

```
LIKE '__.__.____'
```

will do for this case.

Comment: Thank you. It's really simple. Great. Thank you very much!!. @forpas

Comment: Fine if it is solved, but I have to tell you that storing dates a varchar is always a bad idea. If you can change it to Date.

Comment: Now I also know that the date at VARCHAR has nothing to do. Is there any way to convert VARCHAR to DATE? Without losing current records? @forpas

Comment: Yes you can, but first backup. Give me a few mins.

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gW1VjpYHhW4P2zHtNko7j4/1 First you update the column so all the values have the same format 'YYYY-MM-DD', then modify the column's data type. But first **BACKUP**.

Comment: *Check this* I'd recommend to add new field with DATE datatype into the structure, then copy the values with the convertion (2 queries), then check that there is no non-converted values, and if true, then drop old field and rename new. *But first BACKUP* Agreed.

Comment: @Akina I don't disagree, it's another option.

Comment: I performed the 'forpas' test, the test was successful, the modification from VARCHAR to DATE was successful without losing current records. Thank you!!! You helped me a lot today. @forpas

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to validate the numbers, your regular expression is the better route.  However, you need to use the *regular expression* operator:

```
WHERE date_column REGEXP '^\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,2}[.]\d{4}$'
```

Note that `.` is a wildcard in regular expressions.  And based on your question, you want to match the entire string -- not just find the pattern within the string.

If you were to use `like`, you might as well use:

```
where date_column like '%.%.%'
```

This checks that the separators are periods, which is sufficient for distinguishing the two formats.

Comment: Great. Thank you for giving an example with REGEXP. Thank you. @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @PetrFořtFru-Fru . . . This seemed to be more inline with what you were asking for.  If you want an approximate solution, then a simpler `like` pattern (as in this answer) is sufficient.